# How can i report multiple times using reportprogress in a backgroundworker dowork event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Now I can report only one value each time:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {            
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                List<IntPtr> intptrs = GetProcessesIntptrList();
                for (int x = 0; x < intptrs.Count ; x++)
                {
                    GetProcessInfo(intptrs[x]);
                }
                    while (true)
                    {

                        procList = Process.GetProcesses().ToList();
                        for (int i = 0; i < procList.Count; i++)
                        {
                            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(procList[i].ProcessName);
                            PerformanceCounter performanceCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
                            performanceCounter.CategoryName = "Process";
                            performanceCounter.CounterName = "Working Set - Private";//"Working Set";
                            performanceCounter.InstanceName = processes[0].ProcessName;
                            worker.ReportProgress(0, ((uint)performanceCounter.NextValue() / 1024).ToString("N0"));
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
```

And in the progresschanged event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            label4.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
        }
```

But i have more labels or maybe I can create labels according to the number of values there are to report in the loop in the dowork event.

But the idea is to report to each label a value. And not to report all the values on the same label.

Comment: You can send any `object` you like to `ReportProgress`. You could define a class which specifies which label(s) to update with which values, and pass an instance of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, create a custom class to hold the per-process progress that you want to report on.

```
public class MyProgress{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Progress {get;set;}
}
```

If you want to report the cumulative value for all processes once each time the loop executes (i.e. pass a List to the `ReportProgress` call):

```
while (true)
{
    List<MyProgress> prog = new List<MyProgress>();

    procList = Process.GetProcesses().ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < procList.Count; i++)
    {
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(procList[i].ProcessName);
        PerformanceCounter performanceCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
        performanceCounter.CategoryName = "Process";
        performanceCounter.CounterName = "Working Set - Private";//"Working Set";
        performanceCounter.InstanceName = processes[0].ProcessName;

        prog.Add(new MyProgress { Id = procList[i].ProcessName, Progress = ((uint)performanceCounter.NextValue() / 1024).ToString("N0")});
    }

    worker.ReportProgress(0, prog);
}
```

Then update the event handler to do something with our list:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (p in (e.UserState as List<MyProgress>))
    {
        // Just output to console - could update label, etc...
        Console.WriteLine("Progress for {0} is {1}", p.Id, p.Progress);
    }
}
```